# How can I say to JS to increase a value everytime multiple conditions are met..without hardcoding it

Tags: javascript

I  am trying to figure out this problem, basically my problem is:  if  the length (in seconds) is < 180 return 500(pences) . For every extra 60 seconds add 70 pences.  So if for example I have 240seconds I should return 570pences  if I have 300seconds  i should return 640pences and so on. How can I achieve this result with JavaScript?

this is my code so far:

```
    function calculateTaxiFare(seconds) {
        if (seconds < 180) {
   return 500
      // I need something like this without hardcoding
}else if (seconds > 180 && seconds < 240) {
          return 575
}else if ( seconds > 240 && seconds < 300 ) {
          return 640
}
    }

console.log(calculateTaxiFare(245));
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: this is math. You basically need to subtract 180 from seconds, and then divide the result by 60.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to integer divide the (length of time - 180 seconds) by 60 and round upwards to the nearest integer (you can use [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) for that operation) and then multiply that by 70 to get the additional fare, which is then added to the base fare (500):

```js
function calculateTaxiFare(seconds) {
  return 500 + Math.ceil((seconds - 180) / 60) * 70
}

console.log(calculateTaxiFare(245));
```

Comment: `ceil` assumes OP needs to add overprice even if the extra time is not full 60 seconds

Comment: @GrafiCode that's what OP's if block does...

Comment: you're right, just noticed. +1

Comment: This solution work just fine, thank you so much, but I would like to understand better the "logic" to achieve this result.. I know this is not a math lesson :D but If you have the chance to explain a little bit more all the steps and why, I would really appreciated. Anyway thank you so much .

Comment: @VincenzoChiovaro based on your data, the fare is 500 for length <= 180, then goes up by 70 for each 60 second period over 180. So if we subtract 180 from the length, and divide by 60, that gives us the number of periods. But that is a fractional number (e.g. 245 would result = 1.0833) and we need an integer, so we use `Math.ceil` to round it upwards (since we want to charge for each period, no matter how many seconds in the period are used i.e. 1 to 60 seconds in a period all cost the same). Having got that integer, we then multiply by the 70 to get the additional fare to add to the base 500.